# Compressing bitmap fails (Python implementation)

Tags: python, bitmap, bmp

I have an application that uses bitmaps for image storage. Currently these are stored as uncompressed bitmaps, but since the number of colors is almost always <=16, I should be able to use a compressed bitmap format, which makes the files nearly 6 times smaller. With the help of the Wikipedia entry at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format I tried to implement a compression program in Python - shown below. This successfully reads the input bmp and outputs a smaller bmp, but the resulting bmp is not readable, so I must be doing something wrong. In windows explorer, the properties of the file include "Bit Depth: 32", which is clearly not the intention - but I'm pretty sure I got the header info for bit depth and compression right. It would help if I could find an example of a compressed bitmap for inspection, but haven't been able to track one down. Is this format not generally supported, or am I doing something wrong?

```
import math

def rgb(r,g,b):
    return hex(256*256*256+r*256*256+g*256+b)[3:9]
def read_bmp(path):
    bm={}
    with open(path,"rb") as f:
        byte=f.read(54)
        header_size=byte[14]+byte[15]*256
        if header_size!=40: return None
        bm['w']=w=byte[18]+byte[19]*256
        bm['h']=byte[22]+byte[23]*256
        bm['color_depth']=byte[28]
        bm['compression']=byte[30]
        bm['im_size']=byte[34]+byte[35]*256+byte[36]*256*256
        if bm['compression']!=0:
            ct=f.read(4*bm['color_depth'])
            color_table=[]
            for i in range(0,bm['color_depth']):
                color_table.append((ct[i*4],ct[i*4+1],ct[i*4+2]))
        if bm['color_depth']==24:
            bmp=f.read(bm['im_size'])
            row_size=bm['im_size']//bm['h']
            col={}
            pixel=[]
            for y in range(0,bm['h']):
                s=""
                row=[]
                for x in range(0,w):
                    row.append((bmp[y*row_size+x*3],bmp[y*row_size+x*3+1],bmp[y*row_size+x*3+2]))
                    color=rgb(bmp[y*row_size+x*3],bmp[y*row_size+x*3+1],bmp[y*row_size+x*3+2])
                    if color in col:
                        col[color]+=1
                    else:
                        col[color]=1
                pixel.append(row)
            bm['pix']=pixel
            bm['color_count']=len(col)
        return bm
def putint(b,p,i):
    b[p]=i & 255
    b[p+1]=(i>>8)&255
    if i>65535:
        b[p+2]=(i>>16)&255
        b[p+3]=(i>>24)&255
def write_compressed_bmp(bm,path):
    pix=bm['pix']
    col=[]
    color_index=[]
    for row in pix:
        rowindex=[]
        for color in row:
            if not color in col: col.append(color)
            rowindex.append(col.index(color))
        color_index.append(rowindex)
    print(col)
    if len(col)>16: return
    with open(path,"wb") as f:
        row_size=math.ceil(bm['w']/8)*4
        image_size=row_size*bm['h']
        file_len=54+64+image_size
        header=bytearray(54)
        header[0]=ord('B')
        header[1]=ord('M')
        putint(header,2,file_len)
        putint(header,10,54+64)
        putint(header,14,40)
        putint(header,18,bm['w'])
        putint(header,22,bm['h'])
        putint(header,26,1)
        putint(header,28,4)
        putint(header,34,image_size)
        f.write(header)
        color_map=bytearray(64)
        for i in range(0,len(col)):
            color_map[i*4]=col[i][0]
            color_map[i*4+1]=col[i][1]
            color_map[i*4+2]=col[i][2]
        f.write(color_map)
        for row in pix:
            row_bytes=bytearray(row_size)
            i=0
            for color in row:
                ci=col.index(color)
                if i&1:
                    row_bytes[i>>1]|=ci
                else:
                    row_bytes[i>>1]|=ci<<4
                i+=1
            f.write(row_bytes)

bm=read_bmp("bitmap.bmp")
if bm['color_count']<=16:
    write_compressed_bmp(bm,"bitmap2.bmp")
```

Comment: On doing some more reading, I realized that the "compression method"=2 (BI_RLE4) value I set was for run length encoding, which I don't use. The only other possible value that made sense was 0 (no compression), but that results in an "incompatible bitmap format" error trying to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong - I forgot that the range() method in Python takes one larger than the largest desired value as its second parameter, so one too few rows was being written. Fixing that, and leaving the "compression" bit at 0 fixed the problem - I edited the code above accordingly. If it's OK, I'll leave this up here for possible use by others.